# MATLAB can't save each axes mouse-clicks on subplot using ButtonDownFcn

Tags: matlab, subplot, ginput

I have a 3x1 subplot, and I have figured out how to capture the mouse-click coordinates and store them into an array within each axes. However, I'd like to modify my code so that I am able to store the mouse clicks from each axes all in one go around.

Here is my code:

```
function Callbacks

   x = 0:30;
   y1 = 1.5*cos(x);
   y2 = 1.5*cos(x)*10;
   y3 = 1.5*cos(x)*100;

   subplot(3,1,1)
   plot(x,y1,'ButtonDownFcn',{@lineCallBack,'plot1'})

   subplot(3,1,2)
   plot(x,y2,'ButtonDownFcn',{@lineCallBack,'plot2'})

   subplot(3,1,3)
   plot(x,y3,'ButtonDownFcn',{@lineCallBack,'plot3'})

end

function lineCallBack(src,evt,tag_name)

   src.Tag = tag_name;
   N=2;
   P1array = zeros(N,2);
   P2array = zeros(N,2);
   P3array = zeros(N,2);

   for k = 1:N
       if strcmp(tag_name,'plot1')
           [P1array(k,1),P1array(k,2)] = ginput(1);
           hold on;
           plot(P1array(k,1),P1array(k,2),'*r')
       elseif strcmp(tag_name,'plot2')
           [P2array(k,1),P2array(k,2)] = ginput(1);
           hold on;
           plot(P2array(k,1),P2array(k,2),'*r')
       elseif strcmp(tag_name,'plot3')
           [P3array(k,1),P3array(k,2)] = ginput(1);
           hold on;
           plot(P3array(k,1),P3array(k,2),'*r')
       end
   end
```

**OUTPUT**

```
P1array = 
    1 2
    3 4
P2array = 
    0 0
    0 0

P3array = 
    0 0
    0 0
```

As shown on the output above, after clicking through, it seems to only capture the coordinates for the last axes I clicked on. I'd like to be able to have values for all the axes points. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB is doing exactly what you're telling it to do. You are reinitializing all of your arrays every time the callback executes. You need to store your data somewhere.

Comment: @excaza what exactly do you mean by store? can you please provide an example?

Comment: See: [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)